# Flutter 'LatLng' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, leaflet

I am making my first baby steps with Leaflet in Flutter, so patience and URLs of tutorials, etc, are welcome.

Every piece of sample code that I can find gives me this error:

> The method 'LatLng' isn't defined for the type '_MyHomePageState'.
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'LatLng'.

See for instance the answer to [How to setCenter() leaflet map in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746679/how-to-setcenter-leaflet-map-in-flutter/62029556),which has some very straightforward code.

This part of the code

```
  new FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        minZoom: _minzoom,
        maxZoom: _maxzoom,
        center: LatLng(mylatitude,mylongitude),    <=== error here
      ),
```

gives me the error.

I have had the same error with several code samples, copied from the internet. Could it be because I am using the latest version of [the package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map), and those are old posts?

I am using

```
dependencies:
  flutter_map: ^0.9.0
```

As per the [install docs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map#-installing-tab-), but perhaps all the demos I found used something earlier?

I have the same problem with the code from https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map.

It must be something very basic, but, as I said, I am just starting out. Despite familiarity with Leaflet in AngularJs, I am stumped.

What's my problem, and where can I find a good, in-depth, full-featured, tutorial?

[Update] I have completely uninstalled Visual Studio Code (using [Revo Uninstaller Pro](https://www.revouninstaller.com/), which thoroughly scours the registry & file system for left overs. After reinstalling VSC and adding only the Flutter plugin, I still get the problem.

I also installed Android Studio and only the Flutter plugin, with the same result :-(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Import Latlong like below:

```
import "package:latlong/latlong.dart" as latLng;
```

Now you can call Latlong with latLng alias

```
new FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        minZoom: _minzoom,
        maxZoom: _maxzoom,
        center: latLng.LatLng(mylatitude,mylongitude),   
      ),
```

I have similar project which implements MapBox map which is similar to Leaflet map, do check out, here is the link:

https://github.com/TheKetan2/covid19_flutter_app

Comment: Wow!! Thanks ever so much!! I can't understand why this code was working for others. Btw, I just used `import "package:latlong/latlong.dart";`, because the `as` clause gave an error. I suggest it would have required me to use `new latLng.LatLng(90,0, 90.0)`.  I will study your Covid 19 app.  Why MapBox, when Leaflet/OSM is free?

Comment: Welcome. 
MapBox is also free, and it looked better than Leaflet. Initially I was using Leaflet.

Comment: It looks to be [free - up to a point](https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/); am I missing something?

Comment: MapBox does have premium plans too but 25k request were more than enough for my use case so I chose it. You can use Leaflet if it suits your needs :)

Comment: I will check out MapBox, since you recommend it; maybe look for some comparisons Thanks again.

Comment: Btw, my Leaflet map doesn't have zoom controls. I found a demo with a marker, but can't see how to handle clicking on it. Etc. Do you know if there is any documentation for the flutter map package?

Answer (score 24):

For flutter_map 0.13.1 and above, this line should work

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latLng;
```

You can then call LatLng using the alias,

```
FlutterMap(
options: MapOptions(
  center: latLng.LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
  zoom: 13.0,
),
layers: [
  TileLayerOptions(
    urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
  ),
  MarkerLayerOptions(
    markers: [
      Marker(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        point: latLng.LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
        builder: (ctx) =>
        Container(
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
],
```

);

Comment: It is also possible to skip the `as latLng`, then it will only be: `center: LatLng(51.5,-0.09)`

Comment: It works perfectly also in version `0.14.0` ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The latlong2 package makes it more straight forward.

`LatLng` instead of `latLng.LatLng` reduces the risk of human error. simply add:

```
dependencies:
  latlong2: ^0.8.0
```

and

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
```

to get you started, plus you also get these options:

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/Circle.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/Distance.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/LatLng.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/LengthUnit.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/Path.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/calculator/Haversine.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/calculator/Vincenty.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong/interfaces.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/spline.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/spline/CatmullRomSpline.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

dependencies:
google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.8
flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0

Add these packages properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).